# How to filter all rows of a dataframe that matches two criteria of one column in R

Tags: r, dataframe, filter

I have da dataframe in R which looks like that:

```
Name  Online
Paul  Y
Toni  Y
Mike  N
Tim   Y
Mark  N
Paul  N
Mike  Y
Tim   Y
Mark  N
Paul  Y
```

Now I want to filter alls rows, where the Name contains at least once "Y" and  once "N" in the Online column. So for that example my result should look like that:

```
Name  Online
Paul  Y
Mike  N
Paul  N
Mike  Y
Paul  Y
```

Do you know how I can do that in R?
Thanks a lot

Code:

```
Name <- c("Paul","Toni","Mike","Tim","Mark","Paul","Mike","Tim","Mark","Paul")
Online <- c("Y","Y","N","Y","N","N","Y","Y","N","Y")

df <- data.frame(Name, Online)
```

Comment: `df %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(any(Online =="Y")) %>% distinct`

Comment: @akrun, seems like you didn't read the question carefully. Using dplyr, it should be `df %>% group_by(Name) %>% filter(all(c("N", "Y") %in% Online))`

Comment: yeah, I thought it is only 'Y'.

Comment: Thanks a lot for all of your answers - works great now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
y <- df[df$Online == "Y", "Name"] 
n <- df[df$Online == "N", "Name"]
df[df$Name %in% intersect(y,n), ]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
with(df, intersect(Name[Online == 'Y'], Name[Online == 'N']))
#"Paul" "Mike"
```

gives you the names that satisfy the conditions, then you can use `%in%` to select the rows in `df` that satisfy the condition

```
subset(df, Name %in% intersect(Name[Online == 'Y'], Name[Online == 'N'])))
#   Name Online
#1  Paul      Y
#3  Mike      N
#6  Paul      N
#7  Mike      Y
#10 Paul      Y
```

Here the `with` is unnecessary because `subset` already evaluates its second argument in the context of the data frame.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to give you a generic code that you can run for any dataframe.(Nothing is logical here,just smart way---)

```
Name <- c("Paul","Toni","Mike","Tim","Mark","Paul","Mike","Tim","Mark","Paul")
Online <- c("Y","Y","N","Y","N","N","Y","Y","N","Y")
df <- data.frame(Name, Online)

df$new=paste(df[,1],df[,2],sep = "_")
f=unique(df)
f=f[,1:2]

You can use this code just by changing column number.

Hope this will help.
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the data.table package

```
myTable = data.table(myFrame)
bothNames = myTable[(Name %in% myTable[Online == "Y"]$Name) & (Name %in% myTable[Online == "N"]$Name)]
```

Comment: why do you use `data.table` but then don't make any use of it?

Comment: This uses the data.table filter syntax which I find to be cleaner than base R.